# Estimate involving the Markov inequality and the union bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The context: I'm reading a paper about Brownian Motion and $\epsilon$-hitting times on a Torus $\mathbb T_2$. However, I'm a little bit rusty with the basics of probabilty theory so I am not sure how the "$\exists$" is translated into the "$\sum$" in the following statement.

I'm trying to understand the following estimate that is made in some proof in the paper:
$$
\mathbb P(\exists x\in L_\epsilon \textrm{ s.t. } \mathcal T(x) > n_\epsilon(\delta) ) \leq \sum_{x\in L_\epsilon} \mathbb P ( \mathcal T(x) > n_\epsilon(\delta) )
$$
The author states the he used the union bound and the Markov inequality here.

A little bit of context (if additional necessary, please ask):

- $L_\epsilon$ is a square lattice.
- $n_\epsilon(\delta)$ is a fixed value that depends on $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.
- $\mathcal T(x)$ is some sort of excursion count of the Brownian Motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the inequality: for any collection of countably many events $A_n$ (on some probability space)

$$
\mathbb{P}(\cup_n A_n)\leq \sum_{n} A_n.
$$

In your case
$$
\{\exists x\in L_\epsilon \textrm{ s.t. } \mathcal T(x) > n_\epsilon(\delta)\} = \cup_{x\in L_\epsilon}\{\mathcal T(x) > n_\epsilon(\delta)\}.
$$
It is a countable union as it is the square lattice. To see why the equality holds note that, if the event on the left side happens then the event on the right side must happen. Also if the event in the right hand happens then it must happen for at least one $x$, and therefore left side must happen.